# Compile Linux Source in /home

Tags: kernel, partitioning, compiling

I went through many Linux kernel compilation tutorials ... All of them suggest to put the kernel code in `/usr/src` . Is it for any special reason ?

What happen if i compile code in `/home` ? Because my `/usr` have only 4Gb is left.

And he also created a soft link before compiling kernel. Is it necessary ? What is purpose behind it ?

Answer (score 4):

You can compile your kernel in any directory you wish. `/usr/src` is "old school"

Most people advise you compile your kernel as a user, and install as root.

```
make menuconfig
make -j5
sudo cp your_kernel /boot
sudo make modules_install
```

See also

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/kernel

http://kernel-seeds.org/

You can also use the mainline kernels

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

.deb are available here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: I've had serious trouble compiling a kernel in a directory not called '/usr/src/kernel', with kernel being a symlink to the kernel source tree. Maybe things changed over the past 5 years, but I just don't want to find out the hard way.

Comment: That is old school, the kernel used to be compiled as root as well. The reason you would need a link would be compiling additional modules (nvidia, wireless) looking for the source code. Nothing prevents you from `ln -s /home/user/src/kernel /usr/src/kernel`, it is after all a link, does not matter where the source is.

Answer (score 1):

What is the kernel version you are trying to compile?

You can compile the recent versions of the kernel in any folder. In Ubuntu, you can try the following commands:

1. Install the official development tools

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential kernel-package libncurses5-dev fakeroot wget bzip2 git dpkg-dev devscripts
   ```
2. Download the source code for the current kernel version (in any directory)

   ```
   $ mkdir kernel_build
   $ cd kernel_build
   $ apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
   ```
3. Download and build the dependencies

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r)
   ```
4. Go to the downloaded folder, and compile into a installer package

   ```
   $ cd <kernel folder name>
   $ fakeroot debian/rules clean
   $ fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
   ```
5. Install the new kernel, if you want. The new kernel is compiled into a set of installer packages `.deb` in the parent folder.

   ```
   $ cd ..
   $ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```