# How do I set up a partition to use for local files [18.04]

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, filesystem

I recently received notification that my "Filesystem Root" was running out of remaining space. I followed along this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585689/low-disk-space-in-root-filesystem-error). After cleaning up a few folders, this is the output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M  2.1M  787M   1% /run
/dev/sda3        28G   25G  1.9G  93% /
tmpfs           3.9G   26M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop3      5.0M  5.0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/41
/dev/loop2       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4830
/dev/loop0      5.0M  5.0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/39
/dev/loop1       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/sda4       200G  9.6G  180G   6% /mnt/b0267352-7943-4965-bbfc-c0728cd84462
/dev/sda1       234M   16M  218M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs           789M   20K  789M   1% /run/user/124
tmpfs           789M   88K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop5       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
```

After running `sudo baobab /`, I noticed that most of my local files are stored under `/home/username`, including Downloads, Documents, Pictures, etc. Is this normal, and if not, how can I set `/dev/sda4` as the default location for local files?

Alternatively, should I allocate all the space from `/dev/sda4` into `/` to make it bigger? For context, this is all on a single 256G SSD.

Comment: Probably the best solution is to merge sda3 and sda4. But why is sda4 separate anyway?

Comment: I think when I first installed Ubuntu on the SSD, it was recommended that root be no more than 20-30 gigs. It may have been my misunderstanding.

Comment: Typically the 20 to 3-0GB for / is either where you have /home or separate /mnt/data partition for all your data, or a very new user just testing Ubuntu and not saving much data.   You can move /home to sda4, but must backup all data currently in it. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving Or you can make sda4 a data partition, move some or all folders into your new mount & link them back. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Comment: @oldfred thank you, that describes what I was aiming for initially, but I didn't properly partition /home separately. I'll look into moving /home into sda4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a live CD:

- Move your ~10GB of data on your /dev/sda4 to a single new folder.
- Move everything under your /home folder to /dev/sda4.
- Edit your system's /etc/fstab to add a permanent mount of /dev/sda4 at /home, that has now become empty folder on your root filesystem.

reboot!

Comment: How does one move `/home` to the `/dev/sda4` partition?